# Create Vue project with a custom default template

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, boilerplate

I want to create a boiler plate or a base version of a starting project with Vue. When I create a default Vue project with Vue-CLI typing `"vue create my-app"` it gives me a default template with a `HelloWorld.vue` with a prop and with some CSS.

What I want to do is create a custom starting project structure for my works. Can I create a custom command for that? I want to have this boiler plate when I create a new project with `Vue-CLI`. I need to put some specific npm packages by default like `Axios`, `Vue-Router`, `Vuex` or even more specific packages for some of my works.

When I type my custom command, I want to have this default project structure for my Vue project. Instead of having a default `HelloWorld.vue` with Vue logo and some stuff, I want to put my own logo with different components and assets on it.

How do I do that by default? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own NPM cli package, where you will just paste the "files
template" into the directory entered in to the cli.

For more info search for Global NPM package, or view this post https://medium.com/jspoint/creating-cli-executable-global-npm-module-5ef734febe32 . It's kinda easy, GL!

Comment: In this way I don't need vue create command anymore I guess? It'll still be a Vue project but I create the project with my own cli command right?

Comment: Yea kinda, I thinkl there is no way to integrate custom Vue CLI commands